# нужно как-то показать уведомления что есть на смартфоне в моем приложении Юнити

Tags: java, c#, android, unity3d

вот код Java, который в теории должен получать уведомления со смартфона:

```
 package com.alexcompany.readnotification;

 import android.app.Notification;
 import android.content.ComponentName;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.provider.Settings;
 import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService;
 import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification;
 import android.text.TextUtils;
 import android.util.Log;

 import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

 import static android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS;

public class PluginToReadNotifications extends NotificationListenerService {
private static final String TAG = "NotificationListener";
private static final String WA_PACKAGE = "com.whatsapp";
private String ENABLED_NOTIFICATION_LISTENERS;


@Override
public void onListenerConnected() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Notification Listener connected");
}

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    if (!sbn.getPackageName().equals(WA_PACKAGE)) return;

    Notification notification = sbn.getNotification();
    Bundle bundle = notification.extras;

    String from = bundle.getString(NotificationCompat.EXTRA_TITLE);
    String message = bundle.getString(NotificationCompat.EXTRA_TEXT);

   // Log.i(TAG, "From: " + from);
   // Log.i(TAG, "Message: " + message);
   }
 }
```

нужно как-то результат работы этого кода вывести в моем приложении, подскажите пожалуйста, что писать в C# скрипте? заранее спасибо!

Comment: Доя начала нужно создать скрипт. И при чём тут Java?

Comment: @aepot Unity поддерживает вызывание Java классов (Только на Android)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Вам нужно написать **плагин** для `Unity`

Подробнее о том, как это сделать, рассказывается [тут](https://youtu.be/JJE1hsYQYYw)

Comment: Ответ-ссылка не формат для StackOverflow. Приведите ответ в такой вид, чтобы он не превратился в бесполезный, если ссылка перестанет работать. Если вам просто хотелось поделиться ссылкой, а не писать ответ, это можно было сделать в комментариях.

Comment: Предлагаете залить видео на собственный сервер?

Comment: От этого оно не перестанет быть ссылкой. Если вы не знаете, как исправить ответ, перенесите его содержимое в комментарий под вопрос, а ответ удалите.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ! Верно=), мне нужен плагин для юнити=) можно небольшое уточнение: код, который я предоставил возвращает текст, верно? значит мне нужно передавать текст который получил java код, тексту, который у меня есть в юнити? еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Тот, кто найдёт этот вопрос, будет искать что то на подобии "вызов java классов в Unity", думаю моя подсказка значительно поможет. А расписывать, как открыть Android Studio - не вижу нужным

Comment: @Hope1_, да, верно

Comment: понял, спасибо!

Comment: Как это реализовать (c#) вы можете посмотреть в моей библиотеки: https://github.com/AntonRls/AndroidAPIForUnity

Comment: спасибо, прочту!  и еще кое-что: у уведомления на смартфоне ведь есть иконка приложения, от которого оно было выслано... так вот, если ее тоже как-то передавать в юнити, то ведь одним текстом уже не обойдешься, нужно использовать текстуру если объект находится в сцене, и image, если это UI, верно? или как-то можно сделать иначе?

Comment: Думаю в этом случае подойдёт BitMap (Из Android Studio отправляете bitmap и в unity конвертируете его в sprite)

Comment: ого, круто!=) думаю мне нужно будет в этом разобраться, ведь одним текстом выводить уведомления не совсем интересно))